# Angular - upload the changed contents of a previously downloaded file

Tags: angular

After downloading a file, the contents is shown via a simple 'textarea'. The file can be quite large.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <textarea id="filecontent" name="filecontent" [(ngModel)]="filecontent" rows="20"
              required class="form-control" #v_filecontent="ngModel">
        </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

After hitting the 'save' button the contents should be uploaded to the server.

What is the best way to upload the **changed** contents? Especially when the file can be quite large?

Is just creating and sending an object with a filename and a (zipped) file contents the best way?